# PHPUnit throws error on mountain lion

Tags: phpunit

I've followed the instructions exactly described as here
http://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Everything went fine but when i execute the following command

```
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/MoneyTest
```

It throws following error

```
PHPUnit 4.0.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SebastianBergmann\Money\Money' not found in /Users/myname/Sites/lab/unittesting/tests/MoneyTest.php on line 54
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:581
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:132
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:179
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:419
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:722
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:764
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:692
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:824
PHP  10. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:956
PHP  11. SebastianBergmann\Money\MoneyTest->testExceptionIsRaisedForInvalidConstructorArguments() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:956
```

Any idea what might be the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following instructions worked for me:

`$ git clone https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/money`

`$ cd money`

`$ phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php tests/MoneyTest`

```
PHPUnit 3.7.32 by Sebastian Bergmann.

......................

Time: 882 ms, Memory: 3.25Mb

OK (22 tests, 41 assertions)
```

Be aware that I using 3.7.32 and you are using 4.0.4. If its still not working then it could be a bug.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, This worked for me. I didn't get all files before, just copied Money class file and TestMoney class file.